# ESP32 ULP Coprocessor doesn´t wakeup from time

Tags: esp32

My application should initialize the ULP coprocessor and the coprocessor should observe one GPIO. The ULP Timer should wake up the coprocessor in certain intervals and then the coprocessor should check the GPIO and turn on an LED, depending on the state of the GPIO.

I use the following code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <soc/timer_group_reg.h>
#include <soc/timer_group_struct.h>

#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <freertos/event_groups.h>

#include "utils/ulp_utils.h"
#include "shared/shared_Debug.h"
#include "shared/shared_ResetCause.h"

#include <ulp_main.h>

extern "C" void app_main()
{
    if(ResetCause_isPowerOnReset())
    {
        DEBUG_INFO("Power-On-Reset occured!\n");

        DEBUG_INFO("Load ULP program...\n");
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(ulp_load_binary(0, ulp_main_bin_start, (ulp_main_bin_end - ulp_main_bin_start) / sizeof(uint32_t)));
    }
    else if(ResetCause_isDeepSleepReset())
    {
        DEBUG_INFO("Deep sleep Reset occured!\n");

        DEBUG_INFO("Boot counter: ");
        DEBUG_INFO("{%u}\n", (uint16_t)ulp_Status);

        // TODO: Starting application
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_INFO("Unknown reset!\n");

        ResetCause_Print(rtc_get_reset_reason(0));
        ResetCause_Print(rtc_get_reset_reason(1));
    }

    // Start the execution of the ULP code
    DEBUG_INFO("Start ULP program...\n");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(ulp_run(&ulp_entry - RTC_SLOW_MEM));

    // Enable wake up from ULP and enter sleep mode
    DEBUG_INFO("Enter deep sleep...\n");
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(esp_sleep_enable_ulp_wakeup());
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
```

**ulp.S**
#include "soc/soc_ulp.h"
#include "soc/sens_reg.h"
#include "soc/rtc_io_reg.h"
#include "soc/rtc_i2c_reg.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"

```
// The LED is connected on RTC GPIO 6
.set    LED,    6

// The input is connected on RTC GPIO 14y
.set    INPUT,   14

.bss
.global Status
Status:
    .long 0

.text

/** @brief Main entry point for the ULP coprocessor application.
 */
.global entry
entry:
    // Enable the ULP Timer
    WRITE_RTC_FIELD(RTC_CNTL_STATE0_REG, RTC_CNTL_ULP_CP_SLP_TIMER_EN, 1)

    // RTC GPIO 6 is used by the DAC. Enable the GPIO functionality
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_IO_PAD_DAC1_REG, RTC_IO_PDAC1_MUX_SEL_S, 1, 1)

    // Set GPIO 6 as output
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_ENABLE_W1TS_REG, RTC_GPIO_ENABLE_W1TS_S + LED, 1, 1)    

    // Set GPIO 13 as input
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_ENABLE_W1TC_REG, RTC_GPIO_ENABLE_W1TC_S + INPUT, 1, 1)

    // Read the state of the input pin
    READ_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_IN_REG, RTC_GPIO_IN_NEXT_S + INPUT, 1)

    // Save the result
    move    r3, Status
    st      r0, r3, 0

    // Compare the result
    and     r0, r0, 1
    jump    LED_Off, eq
    jump    LED_On

LED_On:
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_W1TS_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_W1TC_S + LED, 1, 1)

    // Wait for 5 seconds
    move    r1, 5000
    move    r2, WakeUp
    jump    Delay_ms

LED_Off:
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_W1TC_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_W1TC_S + LED, 1, 1)

    // Wait for 5 seconds
    move    r1, 5000
    move    r2, Exit
    jump    Delay_ms

/** @brief Disable the coprocessor and wake up the main processor cores.
 */
.global WakeUp
WakeUp:
    // Test if the main processor cores can be woken up by the coprocessor. Leave without wakening up the processor when the function is not enabled.
    READ_RTC_FIELD(RTC_CNTL_LOW_POWER_ST_REG, RTC_CNTL_RDY_FOR_WAKEUP)
    and     r0, r0, 1
    jump    Exit, eq

    // Wake up the main processor cores
    wake

    halt

/** @brief Exit the ULP coprocessor application, power down the coprocessor and restart the wake-up timer.
 */
.global Exit
Exit:
    halt

/** @brief      Delays the program execution by n milliseconds.
 *  @param r1   Delay time in milliseconds
 *  @param r2   Return address
 */
Delay_ms:
    // Wait for 8000 cycles (1 ms @ 8 MHz)
    wait    8000

    // Reduce the counter by one
    sub     r1, r1, 1

    // Jump to the address stored in "r2" if the last ALU operation was zero
    jump    r2, eq

    jump    Delay_ms
```

The ESP gets woken up by the coprocessor as long as the GPIO is high (also the LED is active), but the LED doesn´t light up again after I change the state of the GPIO back from low to high.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip, I don't know if this is the root cause, but I guess in this line  `RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_W1TS_S` should be with S instead of C:

LED_Off:

```
WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_W1TS_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_W1TC_S + LED, 1, 1)
```